# Implementing Metronic Responsive Template in EmberJS

Tags: css, html, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm an Ember beginner. Currently I'm developing a Dashboard web app using EmberJS at front-end side and NodeJS providing RESTful service at the back-end side. I was given this Metronic Responsive Admin Dashboard template to implement in EmberJS. 

My current problem: 
I am trying to render the Metronic's Index page as a Handlebars template in Ember. I have an **index.html** with `{{outlet}}` helper, and an **index.hbs**, where I put the body of the Metronic's Index page. After I compile the template and run the code, the rendered *full-width* page doesn't have the sidebar, while the *resized, half-width* version display correctly.

- *Full-width Page*:
  You can see that there is no button to or space on the left side to toggle the sidebar.
  [full-width page](http://postimg.org/image/4gezprk05/) 
  (pardon me but I don't have enough rep to post picture)
- *Half-width, resized Page*: 
  You can see the sidebar toggle button and the sidebar content.
  [half-width page](http://postimg.org/image/mki0aehol/)

What is the problem here? Why is it only the responsive, resized version can display, while the fullscreen version cannot? Do Ember and Handlebars have anything to do with it?

Code of **index.html** and **index.hbs** are provided below.

- index.html

  ```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <title>Inventory App</title>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
  </head>
  <body class="page-header-fixed page-full-width">
      <!-- Application Entry -->
      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      {{outlet}}
      </script>
      <script src="./scripts/libs.js"></script>
      <script src="./scripts/app.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- index.hbs

  ```
  <div class="page-header-fixed page-sidebar-fixed">
  <!-- declaring stylesheet here -->
  <div class="page-header navbar navbar-fixed-top">
       <!-- header here -->
  </div>
  <div class="page-container">
      <div class="page-sidebar-wrapper">
          <div class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="page-sidebar-menu" data-auto-scroll="false" data-auto-speed="200">
              <!-- list of items here -->
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="page-content-wrapper">
          <!-- page content here -->
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- loading javascript here -->
  </div>
  ```